# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Schema mismatch for label column 'Label': expected Key<UInt32>, got Single Arg_ParamName_Name'

Tags: c#, ml.net

I have this code:

```
        using Microsoft.ML.Data;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace MLPredictor1
    {
        internal class TicketInputDataModel
        {
            [LoadColumn(8)]
            public float state { get; set; }
            [LoadColumn(1)]
            public string? short_description { get; set; }
            [LoadColumn(2)]
            public string? description { get; set; }
            [LoadColumn(3)]
            public string? email { get; set; }
            [LoadColumn(4)]
            public float priority { get; set; }
            [LoadColumn(5)]
            public bool active { get; set; }
            [LoadColumn(6)]
            public DateTime opened_at { get; set; }
            [LoadColumn(7)]
            public float child_incidents { get; set; }
            [LoadColumn(0), ColumnName("Label")]
            public float num_of_days_com { get; set; }
        }
    }

        using Microsoft.ML.Data;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace MLPredictor1
    {
        internal class TicketOutputDataModel
        {
            [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
            public float num_of_days_com { get; set; }
        }
    }


            // See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
        using Microsoft.ML;
        using MLPredictor1;

        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

        List<TicketInputDataModel> ticketInputModel = new List<TicketInputDataModel>();
        ticketInputModel.Add(new TicketInputDataModel() { 
        active = true,
        child_incidents = 4,
        description = "Great to hear that this will be resolved soon",
        email = "john.doe@telefonicatech.uk",
        num_of_days_com = 5,
        opened_at = DateTime.Now,
        priority = 5,
        short_description = "will be resolved soon",
        state = 2
        });

        ticketInputModel.Add(new TicketInputDataModel()
        {
            active = true,
            child_incidents = 6,
            description = "This is taking a bit of time but making progress",
            email = "john.doe@telefonicatech.uk",
            num_of_days_com = 3,
            opened_at = DateTime.Now,
            priority = 1,
            short_description = "progress being made",
            state = 3
        });

        ticketInputModel.Add(new TicketInputDataModel()
        {
            active = true,
            child_incidents = 6,
            description = "This is taking a bit of time but making progress",
            email = "john.doe@telefonicatech.uk",
            num_of_days_com = 3,
            opened_at = DateTime.Now,
            priority = 1,
            short_description = "progress being made",
            state = 3
        });
        ticketInputModel.Add(new TicketInputDataModel()
        {
            active = true,
            child_incidents = 6,
            description = "This is taking a bit of time but making progress",
            email = "john.doe@telefonicatech.uk",
            num_of_days_com = 3,
            opened_at = DateTime.Now,
            priority = 1,
            short_description = "progress being made",
            state = 3
        });
        List<TicketInputDataModel> ticketInputModel2 = new List<TicketInputDataModel>();
        ticketInputModel2.Add(new TicketInputDataModel()
        {
            active = true,
            child_incidents = 6,
            description = "This is taking a bit of time but making progress",
            email = "john.doe@telefonicatech.uk",
            num_of_days_com = 3,
            opened_at = DateTime.Now,
            priority = 1,
            short_description = "progress being made",
            state = 3
        });
        ticketInputModel2.Add(new TicketInputDataModel()
        {
            active = true,
            child_incidents = 6,
            description = "This is taking a bit of time but making progress",
            email = "john.doe@telefonicatech.uk",
            num_of_days_com = 3,
            opened_at = DateTime.Now,
            priority = 1,
            short_description = "progress being made",
            state = 3
        });
        ticketInputModel2.Add(new TicketInputDataModel()
        {
            active = true,
            child_incidents = 6,
            description = "This is taking a bit of time but making progress",
            email = "john.doe@telefonicatech.uk",
            num_of_days_com = 3,
            opened_at = DateTime.Now,
            priority = 1,
            short_description = "progress being made",
            state = 3
        });

        MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

        IDataView? trainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<TicketInputDataModel>(ticketInputModel);

        var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "state", "child_incidents", "priority");

        var multiclassTrainer = pipeline.Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers
            .NaiveBayes(labelColumnName: "Label", featureColumnName: "Features")).Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "short_descriptionEncoded", inputColumnName: nameof(TicketInputDataModel.short_description)));


        ITransformer model = multiclassTrainer.Fit(trainingData); <--- ERROR

        var predictor = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<TicketInputDataModel, TicketOutputDataModel>(model);

        var batchData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<TicketInputDataModel>(ticketInputModel2);
        IDataView predictions = model.Transform(batchData);


        ITransformer model2 = multiclassTrainer.Fit(predictions);

        var predictor2 = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<TicketInputDataModel, TicketOutputDataModel>(model2);


        TicketInputDataModel tt = new TicketInputDataModel()
        {
            active = true,
            child_incidents = 6,
            description = "This is taking a bit of time but making progress",
            email = "john.doe@telefonicatech.uk",
            opened_at = DateTime.Now,
            priority = 1,
            short_description = "progress being made",
            state = 3
        };

        TicketOutputDataModel ttt = predictor2.Predict(tt);
```

Not sure why im getting the error, any hekp?

### Update:

```
MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

        IDataView? trainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<TicketInputDataModel>(ticketInputModel);

        var multiclassTrainer = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("FeaturesText", new[]
    {
        "description",
        "short_description",
        "email",
    })
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("Features", "FeaturesText")).Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers
            .NaiveBayes(labelColumnName: "Label", featureColumnName: "Features"));


        ITransformer model = multiclassTrainer.Fit(trainingData); <-- ERROR

        var predictor = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<TicketInputDataModel, TicketOutputDataModel>(model);

        var batchData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<TicketInputDataModel>(ticketInputModel2);
        IDataView predictions = model.Transform(batchData);


        ITransformer model2 = multiclassTrainer.Fit(predictions);

        var predictor2 = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<TicketInputDataModel, TicketOutputDataModel>(model2);


        TicketInputDataModel tt = new TicketInputDataModel()
        {
            active = true,
            child_incidents = 6,
            description = "This is taking a bit of time but making progress",
            email = "john.doe@telefonicatech.uk",
            opened_at = DateTime.Now,
            priority = 1,
            short_description = "progress being made",
            state = 3
        };

        TicketOutputDataModel ttt = predictor2.Predict(tt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says, the label type is wrong. It's expecting an int but getting a float. Try changing your label field to an int or uint and see if that fixes it.